# How to generate a query string (url) from a form, php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, url

I'm trying to generate a specific url from the form below.
There will be a calendar and the date will go into the url.
Also a value from 9 ticket types and quantities of each of those tickets.
So my url will look something like this

https://sales.site.com/?action=quicksale&venueid=1&businessdate=2012-10-05&ticketids=6,8&quantities=1,1

With these values:
action: always "quicksale",
venueid: always "1",
businessdate: the sales date requested; can be either mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd,
ticketids: see chart below,
quantities: in the order the ticketid's are listed.

How would I approach this, and should I use php or jquery? Post or Get.
Should the calendar be Jquery?

Looking for advice, thanks

```
                        <form method="post" action="">-->
            <div class="quick-book-form-elements">
                <table width="255" class="quick-book-table" cellpadding="4">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="quick-book-days">
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th><img src="../public/img/1day-small.png" alt="" /></th>
                            <th><img src="../public/img/2day-small.png" alt="" /></th>
                            <th class="quick-book-last"><img src="../public/img/3day-small.png" alt="" /></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="quick-book-adults">
                            <th class="quick-book-labels">
                                Adult
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$40/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$50/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="quick-book-last">
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$60/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="quick-book-child">
                            <th class="quick-book-labels">Child</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$30/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$40/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="quick-book-last">
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$50/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="quick-book-family">
                            <th class="quick-book-labels">Family</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$125/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$155/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="quick-book-last">
                                <div class="ticket-style-quick-book">
                                    <select class="adult-ticket-select">
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="quick-book-price">$185/ea</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <a href="http://sales.site.com/" title="" class="quick-book-submit-btn"></a>
        <input type="submit" class="quick-book-submit-btn" name="quick-book-submit-btn" value="" />
    </form>
</div><!-- end quick-book-form div -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For the calendar, indeed you could use the jQuery-ui one. It is a good widget, easy to configure and very powerful.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You can configure it to put the format you want in the input (YYYY-MM-DD for example)

Finally you should add a listener on the submit event, to perform your action modification:

```
// This function will be call before the submit
$("#YOUR_FORM_ID").submit(function(submitEvent) {

    // Initialize the query param array
    var queryParams = [];

    // Fill the query param with values
    queryParams.push("action=quicksale");
    queryParams.push("venueid=1");
    queryParams.push("businessdate=" + $("#YOUR_INPUT_DATE_ID").val());
    // etc...

    // Finally update the form action
    $(this).attr('action', 'https://sales.site.com/?' + queryParams.join("&"));

    // The action has been updated
    // The submit will process
});
```